# Tic Tac Toe with Javascript stuck

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a Tic-Tac-Toe with Javascript.

I used a method to compare the current input with the winning combination.
1)How to determine player 1 and player 2 input ?
2)i can compare 3 , but i can't figure out the 4th click for each player.

Kindly Advise.

```
var check = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]; //check[0] for player 1 , check[1] for player 2 , but i can't figure out how to increase the counter for each player on each click.

function playercol(ideal) //main
            {   

                var idname = "box"+idval;
                var currentcount = (playercount%2);

                if( currentcount == 0 )
                {
                    document.getElementById(idname).innerHTML="O";
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById(idname).innerHTML="X";
                }

                document.getElementById("player").innerHTML="Player "+((playercount%2)+1);
                checkwin(check,0);//to check //0 is the current player index


                playercount++;
            }
```

My Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/1br5LLrj/3/

Comment: FWIW, in your fiddle, `[1,4,5]` is not winning; should be `[1,4,7]`

Comment: Sounds like you might have done homework this week guys. A+!

Comment: @roydukkey There is [nothing wrong with helping with homework](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), as long as the question shows decent effort. After all, there are thousands of Tic Tac Toe implementations out there, and it would be very easy to just copy one of them, which the OP has not done. So I am very happy to help in this case.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 I didn't mean any condemnation. Just noticed you guys gave good answers.

Answer (score 1):

Just made a tic tac toe in about 20 minutes from scratch for you.

[JS Bin Here](http://jsbin.com/niciho/6/)

Just alternating players right now... modify it to your own needs.

all win conditions will alert who winner is:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
function checkwin() {
if (
$('#a1').html() == "X" && $('#b1').html() == "X" && $('#c1').html() == "X" || $('#a2').html() == "X" && $('#b2').html() == "X" && $('#c2').html() == "X" || $('#a3').html() == "X" && $('#b3').html() == "X" && $('#c3').html() == "X" || $('#a1').html() == "X" && $('#a2').html() == "X" && $('#a3').html() == "X" || $('#b1').html() == "X" && $('#b2').html() == "X" && $('#b3').html() == "X" ||
$('#c1').html() == "X" && $('#c2').html() == "X" && $('#c3').html() == "X" ||
$('#a1').html() == "X" && $('#b2').html() == "X" && $('#c3').html() == "X" ||
$('#a3').html() == "X" && $('#b2').html() == "X" && $('#c1').html() == "X"
)
  {
    alert("winner is: X");
  }
if (
$('#a1').html() == "O" && $('#b1').html() == "O" && $('#c1').html() == "O" || $('#a2').html() == "O" && $('#b2').html() == "O" && $('#c2').html() == "O" || $('#a3').html() == "O" && $('#b3').html() == "O" && $('#c3').html() == "O" || $('#a1').html() == "O" && $('#a2').html() == "O" && $('#a3').html() == "O" || $('#b1').html() == "O" && $('#b2').html() == "O" && $('#b3').html() == "O" ||
$('#c1').html() == "O" && $('#c2').html() == "O" && $('#c3').html() == "O" ||
$('#a1').html() == "O" && $('#b2').html() == "O" && $('#c3').html() == "O" ||
$('#a3').html() == "O" && $('#b2').html() == "O" && $('#c1').html() == "O"
)
  {
    alert("winner is: O");
  }
}  

var player = 1;
$('td').click(function(){
if(player == 1){
$(this).html("X").removeClass('o').addClass('x');
checkwin();
player++;
}
  else if (player == 2){
    $(this).html("O").removeClass('x').addClass('o');
checkwin();
player--;
  }
});
});
```

Dont forget to use Jquery Library!

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to modify your code as little as possible http://jsfiddle.net/rrj24ze9/1

The essential part is the win check:

You don't need to remember what the player has clicked and compare that to a winning combo. Instead, iterate through the winning combinations and check if one of them contains only fields that are taken by the player.

```
var winning = [
    [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9],
    [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9],
    [1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7]
];

function checkwin(player) {
    for (var i = 0; i < winning.length; i++) {
        var combo = true;
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (document.getElementById('box' + winning[i][j]).innerHTML != markers[player]) {
                combo = false;
            }
        }
        if (combo) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

There is a lot of potential for improvement, like not using `innerHTML` (separation of data from view), or even preventing two clicks on the same field, but again, I tried to leave your code intact where possible.